Headless UI Modal only transitioning on way in (open), not fading out properly on close
code is setup as shown, TransisitonChild should work for open and close:
when modal is opened, it fades in properly with translate-y, but it is not fading out on close, just instantly closing.
Similar to: https://headlessui.com/react/dialog
Should be working for both open and close as it does on the headless website example.
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogPanel,
  DialogTitle,
  Transition,
  TransitionChild,
} from "@headlessui/react";
import { CheckIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";

interface FeedbackProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}

const Feedback: React.FC<FeedbackProps> = ({ open, onClose }) => {
  return (
    <Transition appear show={open}>
      <Dialog className="relative z-10" onClose={onClose}>
        <TransitionChild
          enter="ease-out duration-300"
          enterFrom="opacity-0"
          enterTo="opacity-100"
          leave="ease-in duration-200"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0"
        >
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
        </TransitionChild>

        <div className="fixed inset-0 z-10 w-screen overflow-y-auto">
          <div className="flex min-h-full items-end justify-center p-4 text-center sm:items-center sm:p-0">
            <TransitionChild
              enter="ease-out duration-300"
              enterFrom="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
              enterTo="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
              leave="ease-in duration-200"
              leaveFrom="opacity-100 translate-y-0 sm:scale-100"
              leaveTo="opacity-0 translate-y-4 sm:translate-y-0 sm:scale-95"
            >
              <DialogPanel className="relative transform overflow-hidden rounded-lg bg-white px-4 pb-4 pt-5 text-left shadow-xl transition-all sm:my-8 sm:w-full sm:max-w-lg sm:p-6">
                <div>
                  <div className="mx-auto flex h-12 w-12 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-green-100">
                    <CheckIcon
                      className="h-6 w-6 text-green-600"
                      aria-hidden="true"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="mt-3 text-center sm:mt-5">
                    <DialogTitle
                      as="h3"
                      className="text-base font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-900"
                    >
                      Payment successful
                    </DialogTitle>
                    <div className="mt-2">
                      <p className="text-sm text-gray-500">
                        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Eius aliquam laudantium explicabo pariatur iste
                        dolorem animi vitae error totam. At sapiente aliquam
                        accusamus facere veritatis.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="mt-5 sm:mt-6 sm:grid sm:grid-flow-row-dense sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-3">
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600 sm:col-start-2"
                    onClick={onClose}
                  >
                    Submit
                  </button>
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    className="mt-3 inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-white px-3 py-2 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-50 sm:col-start-1 sm:mt-0"
                    onClick={onClose}
                    data-autofocus
                  >
                    Close
                  </button>
                </div>
              </DialogPanel>
            </TransitionChild>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition>
  );
};

export default Feedback;

